# How to get pure data out of immutablejs list

Tags: immutable.js

So I have a List and I am able to filter to find on it which works fine for reducing the list to what I am looking for.
However, let's say I just want to get back an array of numbers, not a List, back from my search, something like:

```
 var found = campaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModels.map((campaignTime) => {
                    if (campaignTime.getId() == num)
                        return Math.random();
                });
```

The problem is that `found` is now still a List, and 2, is that I have a undefined members in this List as it seems to hold the same size as my original List.
So Map didn't do it. 
All I am trying to do is get back a simple list of pure numbers that match a condition back as a pure array.

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

found it, magic of reduce:

```
  var IDs = campaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModels.reduce((result,campaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModel: CampaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModel)=>{
                    if (campaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModel.getCampaignTimelineId() == i_campaign_timeline_id)
                        result.push(campaignTimelineBoardTemplatesModel.getCampaignTimelineId());
                    return result;
                },[])
```